Reddit auth error 401 when running autopost command in discord.js bot
I’m running into some trouble with my Discord bot that’s supposed to fetch images from Reddit. I keep hitting this error:
Error obtaining Reddit access token: { message: 'Unauthorized', error: 401 } Error fetching images from Reddit: Error: Failed to obtain Reddit access token     at /home/******/Desktop/discordBot/commands/REdditspam.js:34:11     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)     at async getRedditImages (/home/******/Desktop/discordBot/commands/REdditspam.js:26:22)     at async Timeout.spamLoop [as _onTimeout] (/home/******/Desktop/discordBot/commands/REdditspam.js:138:22) Error in redditspam execution: Error: Failed to fetch images from Reddit     at getRedditImages (/home/******/Desktop/discordBot/commands/REdditspam.js:57:11)     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)     at async Timeout.spamLoop [as _onTimeout] (/home/******/Desktop/discordBot/commands/REdditspam.js:138:22)
here is the full code:
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const axios = require('axios');
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const fs = require('fs'); // Required for file logging

const activeSpams = new Map(); // Map to store active spams by guild ID and channel ID
const imageCache = new Map(); // Map to store cached images by guild ID and channel ID

// MongoDB configuration
const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI; // Replace with your MongoDB connection URI
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

// Reddit API configuration
const redditClientId = process.env.REDDIT_CLIENT_ID; // Replace with your Reddit client ID
const redditClientSecret = process.env.REDDIT_CLIENT_SECRET; // Replace with your Reddit client secret
const redditUserAgent = 'Discord Bot (YourAppName)';

// Log file path
const logFilePath = './redditspam_log.txt';

// Function to get the newest images from a subreddit
async function getRedditImages(subreddit, limit = 10) {
  try {
    // Get access token from Reddit
const authResponse = await axios.post('https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token', 
  'grant_type=client_credentials', {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Basic ${Buffer.from(`${redditClientId}:${redditClientSecret}`).toString('base64')}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error("Error obtaining Reddit access token:", err.response ? err.response.data : err.message);
    throw new Error("Failed to obtain Reddit access token");
  });

    const accessToken = authResponse.data.access_token;

    // Fetch newest posts from the subreddit
    const response = await axios.get(`https://oauth.reddit.com/r/${subreddit}/new.json?limit=${limit}`, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        'User-Agent': redditUserAgent
      }
    });

    // Filter and map image posts
    return response.data.data.children
      .filter(post => post.data.post_hint === 'image')
      .map(post => ({
        imageUrl: post.data.url,
        title: post.data.title,
        author: post.data.author
      }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching images from Reddit:", error);
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch images from Reddit");
  }
}

// Function to log the image URL
function logImageUrl(url) {
  const logMessage = `Image URL: ${url} - ${new Date().toISOString()}\n`;
  fs.appendFile(logFilePath, logMessage, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Error logging image URL:", err);
    }
  });
}

async function logActiveSpams() {
  console.log("Active Spams:");
  for (const [key, value] of activeSpams.entries()) {
    console.log(`Guild ID: ${key.split('-')[0]}, Channel ID: ${key.split('-')[1]}, Interval: ${value}`);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('redditspam')
    .setDescription('Start or stop sending the newest images from Reddit subreddits')
    .addStringOption(option =>
      option
        .setName('action')
        .setDescription('Start or stop spamming')
        .setRequired(true)
        .addChoices(
          { name: 'Start', value: 'start' },
          { name: 'Stop', value: 'stop' }
        ))
    .addStringOption(option =>
      option
        .setName('subreddit')
        .setDescription('Subreddit to fetch images from')
        .setRequired(false))
    .addIntegerOption(option =>
      option
        .setName('interval')
        .setDescription('Interval between sending images (in minutes)')
        .setRequired(false)),

  async execute(interaction) {
    const action = interaction.options.getString('action');
    const subreddit = interaction.options.getString('subreddit') || 'pics'; // Default to 'pics' subreddit
    let interval = interaction.options.getInteger('interval');

    // Validate interval to be between 1 and 20
    if (interval && (interval < 1 || interval > 20)) {
      await interaction.reply({ content: "Interval must be between 1 and 20 minutes.", ephemeral: true });
      return;
    }

    const guildId = interaction.guildId;
    const channelId = interaction.channelId;
    const spamKey = `${guildId}-${channelId}`;

    if (action === 'start') {
      if (activeSpams.has(spamKey)) {
        await interaction.reply({ content: "There's already an active redditspam in this channel.", ephemeral: true });
        return;
      }

      await interaction.reply({ content: "Reddit spam started!", ephemeral: true });

      const spamLoop = async () => {
        try {
          if (!interaction.channel.nsfw) {
            await interaction.channel.send("This command can only be used in NSFW channels.");
            clearInterval(activeSpams.get(spamKey));
            activeSpams.delete(spamKey);
            return;
          }

          let images = imageCache.get(spamKey);

          // If image cache is empty or outdated, fetch new images
          if (!images || images.length === 0) {
            images = await getRedditImages(subreddit);
            imageCache.set(spamKey, images);
          }

          // Send the newest image in the list
          const { imageUrl, title, author } = images.shift(); // Use shift to get the first image

          // Create an embed message
          const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle(title)
            .setDescription(`Posted by ${author}\n[View Image](${imageUrl})`)
            .setImage(imageUrl)
            .setColor('#FF4500');

          // Send the embed message
          await interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });

          // Log the image URL
          logImageUrl(imageUrl);

          // Fetch new images if the cache is empty
          if (images.length === 0) {
            images = await getRedditImages(subreddit);
            imageCache.set(spamKey, images);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error in redditspam execution:", error);
          await interaction.channel.send("Something went wrong. Sorry");
          clearInterval(activeSpams.get(spamKey));
          activeSpams.delete(spamKey);
        }
      };

      // Start the spam loop only if the interval is valid
      if (interval) {
        const spamInterval = setInterval(spamLoop, interval * 60 * 1000); // Convert minutes to milliseconds

        // Store active spams in MongoDB
        try {
          await mongoClient.connect();
          const database = mongoClient.db('bot_db'); // Replace with your MongoDB database name
          const collection = database.collection('activespams');

          await collection.insertOne({ spamKey, guildId, channelId, interval });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error storing active spam in MongoDB:", error);
        } finally {
          await mongoClient.close();
        }

        activeSpams.set(spamKey, spamInterval);
      } else {
        await interaction.channel.send({ content: "Interval must be provided and be between 1 and 20 minutes.", ephemeral: true });
      }

    } else if (action === 'stop') {
      if (!activeSpams.has(spamKey)) {
        await interaction.reply({ content: "There's no active redditspam in this channel.", ephemeral: true });
        return;
      }

      // Remove active spam from MongoDB
      try {
        await mongoClient.connect();
        const database = mongoClient.db('bot_db'); // Replace with your MongoDB database name
        const collection = database.collection('activespams');

        await collection.deleteOne({ spamKey });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error removing active spam from MongoDB:", error);
      } finally {
        await mongoClient.close();
      }

      clearInterval(activeSpams.get(spamKey));
      activeSpams.delete(spamKey);
      await interaction.reply({ content: "Reddit spam stopped!", ephemeral: true });
    }

    // Log active spams
    await logActiveSpams();
  },
};

`
A few things I’ve checked:
Credentials: I’ve double-checked my Reddit app credentials (client ID and secret) and they seem fine.
Authorization Header: The authorization header for the access token request looks to be fine? i looked at a few solutions.
Scopes: I’m using client_credentials grant type`

Any ideas on what might be going wrong? Could it be an issue with Reddit’s API or my request setup?
Thanks in advance for any insights!
